# Visual Studio 2013 designer for Windows Phone not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I have Windows 8.1 on a Virtual Machine (Oracle VirtualBox). I use this machine to develop apps on my windows phone (directly on the phone, not via emulators). 
Everything worked fine for a long while and suddenly, out of nowhere, the designer stopped working...

The problem looks like this:

[image: http://imgur.com/X3IDOwj]

I can add controls, however I cannot see them in the designer, only shows some black square at top-left of the phone designer. (It works fine later on the phone, but I cannot view it in Visual Studio). There are no errors anywhere. It is really annoying and I cannot seem to find any answer so far...

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Keran.

Comment: you are having datatemplates ,datatemplates does not show in design view try adding simple textbox not inside  page.resources and check if you can see it,Page resources will never show in designview

Comment: I actually opened many Windows Phone projects, already finished by me. Designer always showed something and now it stopped... So yes, my controls are outside the page.resources and its still empty... Same happens for user controls, so it's the designer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Posted by Varun Mashru on 5/23/2014 at 3:54 AM on Visual Studio Feedback Forum***

> Surprisingly and fortunately, I found the solution just two days ago.
>   It is a bit of a bummer but that's what it is.
>
> It has nothing to do with the VS setup or the OS.
>
> The first thing to notice here is that it happens with notebooks only.
>   The REASON??
>
> Because notebooks do not have completely dedicated GPUs. These GPUs
>   act as secondary processors for the onboard graphics solution which is
>   directly connected to the display. Hence they fire up only when
>   needed.
>
> My notebook is a Dell Inspiron 15 3537 -- Core i5 4200U (Intel HD Graphics
>   4400 onboard) + AMD Radeon HD 8670M. It has a switchable graphics
>   solution. Hence the software chooses as to which GPU does the
>   weight-lifting.
>
> The power settings, when cranked up to the max, indicate that the AMD
>   GPU must be the one that should take the lead.
>
> And in the case of VS it does not happen properly (Don't know why??).
>   Maybe the UI components can't decide which GPU processor to choose
>   or whatever.
>
> So the simple workaround I found was to bring the graphics settings
>   down by just a notch. Which is selecting the 'Optimize Performance'
>   option in the Switchable Graphics instead of the 'Maximize Performance'
>   field in the power plans.
>
> And voila, It works perfectly fine!!!!
>
> Share this with everyone who has freaked out for months on this
>   issue!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Though the answer from Hassan El-Zarkawy is also useful, the real problem for me was with Oracle Virtual Box...

**At some point I have turned on 3D acceleration for the VM.** This messed up the designer in the Visual Studio. **As soon as I turned it off**, everything worked fine, even on the high performance battery setting.

I don't know if it matters, but I also switched to **1 core for the virtual machine**, it seems to work better now apparently...

Anyway, thanks for the help.